# Преобразовать список в словарь python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dict

Как из списка:

```
[['Account', 'Sony', 'Sony'], ['Campaign', 'Sony_Brand', 'Sony_Generic'], ['Clicks', 300, 70]]
```

сделать словарь:

```
{'Account': ['Sony', 'Sony'], 'Campaign': ['Sony_Brand', 'Sony_Generic'], 'Clicks': [300, 70]}
```

Comment: `{'Account': 'Sony', 'Sony',` тут ошибка синтаксиса. Мб, нужно `{'Account': ['Sony', 'Sony'],`?

Comment: @gil9red да, исправил

Comment: А я не дожидаясь вашего ответа решил попробовать сделать алгоритм для предполагаемого формата :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

- Создается словарь через генератор
- В качестве ключа берется первый элемент списка
- В качестве значения указываются список из второго элемента и до конца списка

Пример:

```
items = [['Account', 'Sony', 'Sony'], ['Campaign', 'Sony_Brand', 'Sony_Generic'], ['Clicks', 300, 70]]

d = {x[0]: x[1:] for x in items}
print(d)
# {'Account': ['Sony', 'Sony'], 'Campaign': ['Sony_Brand', 'Sony_Generic'], 'Clicks': [300, 70]}
```